# Comparing String inputs to desired length

Tags: java

I am running this program which taking inputs from command line for t(Desired Length),no of  test
     cases(N). But it is giving a run time error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index
    out of range: -1
        at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.insert(AbstractStringBuilder.java:979)
      at java.lang.StringBuilder.insert(StringBuilder.java:300)
        at Test.main(Test.java:28)
```

I am getting confused where i am accessing wrong index.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
class TestClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int t = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        String line = br.readLine();
        int N = Integer.parseInt(line);
        String[] profiles = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            profiles = br.readLine().trim().split(" ");
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            if (Integer.parseInt(profiles[0]) > t && Integer.parseInt(profiles[1]) == t ||
                    Integer.parseInt(profiles[0]) > t || Integer.parseInt(profiles[1]) > t
                    || Integer.parseInt(profiles[0]) == t && Integer.parseInt(profiles[1]) > t)
            {
                System.out.println("Crop");
            }
            if (Integer.parseInt(profiles[0]) < t && Integer.parseInt(profiles[1]) < t) {
                System.out.println("Upload next");
            }

            if (Integer.parseInt(profiles[0]) == t && Integer.parseInt(profiles[1]) == t) {
                System.out.println("Accepted");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

Comment: "where I am accessing wrong index" is easy to answer: `Test.java` line 28

Comment: what line is it in your file ? could you add a comment to locate it ?

Comment: What's the goal of your code? Check if the _N_ strings are shorter, equals to or longer than _t_?

Comment: @Sam  it is giving System.out.println("Upload next")...if that would have given me a error at some other line then it would be easy for me..to debug but it is giving at line 28-->System.out.println("Upload next").

Comment: @Giulio I am trying -->First line contains Length=t.
Second line contains N, number of photos.
Following N lines each contains two space separated integers Width and Height.

Comment: @Tom & Setu & Brian & Amitesh & Giulio & Sam & RC ..thanks guys now my cod is working fyn..problem was with initilization for string arrray ..tHis  works String [] profiles=new String[N]; insted of String [] profiles=null ANDDDDDDD  i used this if (line!=null && (line.trim().equals("") || line.trim().length() <= 0)) before going for actual comparing and all.. :-)

Comment: `String [] profiles=new String[N];` won't change much if you still use `profiles = br.readLine().trim().split(" ");` inside the loop. I guess you changed that to `profiles[i] = br.readLine().trim()`?

Comment: @Tom when em using profiles[i] = br.readLine().trim() then it is giving error as                                           Test.java:16: incompatible types
found   : java.lang.String[]
required: java.lang.String
                   profiles[i]=br.readLine().trim().split(" "); at spilt()

Comment: Please check my comment again. "My" line was `profiles[i] = br.readLine().trim()` not `profiles[i]=br.readLine().trim().split(" ");` (mention the missing `split(" ")` call). But anyway, you said your code works now, so you still use `profiles = br.readLine().trim().split(" ");`? If yes, then I wonder how `String [] profiles=new String[N];` could solve anything. I guess the new code `if (line!=null && (line.trim().equals("") || line.trim().length() <= 0))` is the real solution to your problem (but it is just a guess).

Comment: @Tom you are right about profiles[i] = br.readLine().trim()... and this is not the solution if (line!=null && (line.trim().equals("") || line.trim().length() <= 0))...it doesnt work ..String [] profiles=new String[N];actualy when i am initializing String [] profiles=null then it giving error for my first input as.               Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
        at Test.main(Test.java:16)

Comment: The problem is, it doesn't matter which value `profiles` has, if you really use `profiles = br.readLine().trim().split(" ");` inside the first loop. I use your code of the question to test that. Have you changed it so it differs from the code where you get the `NullPointerException`?

Comment: @Tom yes..i chnged ..removed some initilization probblems..but for my program em expecting like..t=180 which will be like B*H=180*180, then no of test cases like 2...then user inputs 198 190 then [ENTER] 38 78 ..then ourout should be two mesgs crop and upload another

Answer (score 0):

Your coding is unsafe, as you use the indexes `[0]` and `[1]` on `profiles` without checking that this array has any elements. Further you loop around overwriting the contents of `profiles` in a loop. What happens when there is no text to read from `br`?

You should always check the values before access (as in defensive programming).

Perhaps some [Rubber Duck debugging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) is needed here.

Comment: @Brian..thanks brian i missed this point..i will replace it with if (line!=null && (line.trim().equals("") || line.trim().length() <= 0))

Answer (score 0):

Here Lies the Demon in your Code :

```
 // Let t=3 and N=5
    String [] profiles=null; // Let the Input Here Be 12, 23, 34, 45, 56
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        profiles=br.readLine().trim().split(" ");
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(profiles));  // [56] Only ? because you are initializing the same rer again and again
```

So when execution Goes Here :

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
    if (Integer.parseInt(profiles[0]) > t && 
        Integer.parseInt(profiles[1]) == t || ... // Throws Index out of bounds exception
```

**EDIT 1 :** Here is the full Working Code :

```
package com.stackoverflow;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int t = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        System.out.println(t);
        String line = br.readLine();
        int N = Integer.parseInt(line);
        System.out.println(N);
        String[] profiles = new String[N];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            profiles[i] = br.readLine().trim();
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(profiles[0]) > t && Integer.parseInt(profiles[1]) == t);
            System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(profiles[0]) > t || Integer.parseInt(profiles[1]) > t);
            System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(profiles[0]) == t && Integer.parseInt(profiles[1]) > t);
            if (Integer.parseInt(profiles[0]) > t && Integer.parseInt(profiles[1]) == t ||
                    Integer.parseInt(profiles[0]) > t || Integer.parseInt(profiles[1]) > t
                    || Integer.parseInt(profiles[0]) == t && Integer.parseInt(profiles[1]) > t)
            {
                System.out.println("Crop");
            }

            System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(profiles[0]) < t && Integer.parseInt(profiles[1]) < t);
            if (Integer.parseInt(profiles[0]) < t && Integer.parseInt(profiles[1]) < t) {
                System.out.println("Upload next");
            }

            System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(profiles[0]) == t && Integer.parseInt(profiles[1]) == t);
            if (Integer.parseInt(profiles[0]) == t && Integer.parseInt(profiles[1]) == t) {
                System.out.println("Accepted");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

**EDIT 2 :** Adding the Test Cases for the ***if*** conditions inside for loop :

*Test Case1 Values :* Let t=3, N=5 and the values for five(i.e N) test case be 12, 23, 34, 45, 56

Prints "crop" to the Console.

*Test Case2 Values :* Let t=30, N=5 and the values for five(i.e N) test case be 12, 23, 34, 45, 56

Prints "upload next" to the Console.

*Test Case3 Values :* Let t=10, N=5 and the values for five(i.e N) test case be 10, 20, 34, 45, 56

Prints "Accepted" to the Console.

Comment: yeah this is right.. but when i did this..it giving output as  "Crop" for every input ..do you think it has to do something with this condition  if (Integer.parseInt(profiles[0]) > t && Integer.parseInt(profiles[1]) == t ||
                    Integer.parseInt(profiles[0]) > t || Integer.parseInt(profiles[1]) > t
                    || Integer.parseInt(profiles[0]) == t && Integer.parseInt(profiles[1]) > t)

Comment: @MohitDarmwal Yes, One among the defined conditions is turning out to be true and since you are using || operator, This will be executed

Comment: with this condition profiles=br.readLine().trim().split(" "); it is taking 2 test case vales like if i am having 2 test cases with values 180 180 and 456 564 with t=180 then it is only comparing 456 564..why ist overriding the previous input..and not handling that???

Comment: @MohitDarmwal, Also it totally depends on the values you are passing into the profiles[] array

Comment: @MohitDarmwal Because profiles=br.readLine().trim().split(" "); always creates a new Array. So only the values for the Last Test case will be availbale with it

Comment: this makes sense..i will go with it..but for my second loop where i am checking conditions it is not actually checking anythning..now my input is coming as profiles[i]=br.readLine().trim();

Comment: @MohitDarmwal No, It's not true. It is always evaluating the condition. I am Posting the full code. Just Copy it and run on your system with the Test Case Values Given below the Code.

Comment: @Amitesh..your code is fine..and i am glad you have reedit n posted runng version here..but for my program em expecting like..t=180 which will be like B*H=180*180, then no of test cases like 2...then user inputs 198 190 then [ENTER] 38 78 ..then ourout should be two mesgs crop and upload another...

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand the checks you want to do, but if you want to check if each string is longer, shorter or equals to *t*, you should use this code:

```
public class Main
{
    private static BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));


    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        int t = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        int N = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        /* MUST INITIALISE BEFORE FILLING IT! */
        String [] profiles = new String[N];
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            profiles[i] = br.readLine().trim();
            if (profiles[i].length() < t)
                System.out.println("shorter than t");// do something
            else if (profiles[i].length() == t)
                System.out.println("equals to t");// do something
            else
                System.out.println("longer than t");// do something
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using a buffer reader to read some lines, with System.in . And before closing this buffer you try to make use of System.out . Could it be the reason for your trouble ? I think that asking the System to write and read at the same time is definitely not a good idea. Can you try to put a br.close() before the second loop ?